# How to set the value of a div

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of writing a small quiz app and am looking at different ways of setting the value of a div or text field

As a learning process, I have attempted to set the value of page elements using a number of different methods

1. document.form1.questionDisplay.value = VALUE// This works - I'm targeting a textarea by "name"
2. document.getElementById("showQuestion2").innerHTML = VAULE //This works using the getElementById method.
3. document.showQuestion3.value=   allQuestions[2].question+"\n"+allQuestions[2]
   THIS is doesnt work. this returns - TypeError: document.showQuestion3 is undefined.  Is my    mistake:
   a. misunderstanding the syntax document.element_name.value is just plain incorrect
4. document.showQuestion3.innerHTML= allQuestions[2].question+"\n"+allQuestions[2]….
    this returns - document.showQuestion3 is undefined

What I am attempting to confirm is:

When using forms, you can navigate the DOM/BOM via the name property to set/retrieve values

When attempting to change/set the HTML of an element, you cannot use the nomenclature:
 document.ID.innerHTML - you need to use the getElementbyID method, there is no way to do it otherwise

**SAMPLE/EXPERIMENTAL CODE**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                function btnShowQuestion_onclick(){
                    var allQuestions = [
                        {question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
                        choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
                        correctAnswer:0},
                        {question: "What is Superman's real name?",
                        choices: ["Carmen Electra", "Gordon Brown", "Clark Kent", "Tony Blair"],
                        correctAnswer:2},

                        {question: "What if god was one of us?",
                        choices: ["would he be a stranger on the bus", "Would he be a cat ", "she would do a duet with britney spears", "it would smite you dead"],
                        correctAnswer:2}
                    ];

                    document.form1.questionDisplay.value = allQuestions[0].question+"\n"+allQuestions[0].choices+"\n";
                    document.getElementById("showQuestion2").innerHTML = allQuestions[1].question+"\n"+allQuestions[1].choices+"\n";
                    document.showQuestion3.value= allQuestions[2].question+"\n"+allQuestions[2].choices+"\n";
                };


            </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">

           <h1>Let' play a game</h1>

            <div id="showQuestion2"></div>
             <div name="showQuestion3"></div>
            <form name="form1" action="">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="questionDisplay"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="show question" name="btnShowVisited" onclick="btnShowQuestion_onclick()" />
            </form>


      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you phrase your question in the form of a question?

Comment: No question mark "?" in your attempt at a question means this is unclear what you are asking and should be closed.

Comment: `document.showQuestion3.value` fails for the reason you listed above; but `document.getElementById('showQuestion3').value` would still fail: `div` elements don't have values. They have contents, which you can set via `innerHTML`, by adding child nodes, etc.

Comment: `document.form1.questionDisplay.value` is the very old legacy DOM syntax and while outdated, is still valid in most browsers. You should use the more modern `document.getElementById("showQuestion2").innerHTML` syntax instead.

Comment: @j08691 - the guidance is appreciated. will be sticking with the getElementById syntax. The purpose for me in doing this was to get a better understanding of the basic mechanics

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you too take a look at jsrender jquery library where you can dynamically generate user interface with simple notations and using ajax calls.
take a look at this[https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender] for more reference

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div>
        {{:#index+1}}: <b>{{>name}}</b> ({{>releaseYear}})
    </div>
</script>

<div id="movieList"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var movies = [
        { name: "The Red Violin", releaseYear: "1998" },
        { name: "Eyes Wide Shut", releaseYear: "1999" },
        { name: "The Inheritance", releaseYear: "1976" }
    ];
    // Render the template with the movies data and insert
    // the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element
    $( "#movieList" ).html(
        $( "#movieTemplate" ).render( movies )
    );
</script>
```

In above code movies data is rendered in movieList div using script tags

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (although it's difficult to understand exactly what's being asked), and this is a plain vanilla JavaScript question and suggesting that jQuery is needed is a bad idea. Notice no jQuery tag.

Comment: I am just providing a solution for dynamically loading data into a div element logically and I think its better than setting .innerHTML every time, There is nothing to down vote it.

Comment: This also makes code more readable and maintainable than using javascript .innerHTML